# "This code is for an app that is not compatible with this device."

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an app in the Apple App Store that we can't seem to get installed on a Verizon iPhone <sub><sup>(from the App Store, not Xcode)</sup></sub>. This may have nothing to do with the fact that it's a Verizon device, but that is the main difference I see between it and the devices I can get to run it.

We are attempting to install the app using a **promotional code**, but we receive an error when hitting <kbd>Redeem</kbd>, as seen in this picture: <sub><sup>(promo code blocked out)</sup></sub>

[image: Redemption Error]

<sub><sup>**ERROR:**</sup>   *<sup>This code is for an app that is not compatible with this device. You can redeem it on your desktop computer or a compatible device.</sup>*</sub>

The error device is an iPhone 4 (Verizon) running **iOS 4.2.8**.  This error was received when the app was built for 3.x and the *assumption* was that Verizon devices would not accept apps not built with at least SDK 4.

However, the app was recently updated (yesterday) to use the **4.3 SDK**. The app has its deployment target set to **iOS 3.1** and has been successfully installed and tested on a device (iPhone 3G AT&T) running this version. This latest version has also been successfully retrieved and tested on an iPhone 4 (AT&T) running 4.3. We were under the impression that every version in-between (3.1 - 4.3) would then be compatible, perhaps this is not the case?

Unfortunately, the Verizon device is not available for Xcode deployment nor ad hoc distribution.

**Now for the actual development question:**
Is there a build setting that can explain this behavior? Failing that, I would like to determine if the error is limited to the specific device or all devices either running 4.2.8 or Verizon specific hardware.

<sub><sup>I would be willing to share a promotional code or two to people running 4.2.8 (or later) on a Verizon device (This is **not** a bribe. You are welcome to keep the app of course, but I am offering this only for installation testing purposes, **not** for promotional reasons). If you think you can help, please indicate your interest in the comments. I have not mentioned the app here, because I don't want to unnecessarily spam my product if the answer can be determined without it, but I have no problem sharing that information if required.</sup></sub>

---

### Update:

I followed [lxt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197143/lxt) [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943742/app-incompatible-with-verizon-iphone/6944065#6944065) and waited to see if it was a caching issue with the App Store servers. Unfortunately, 40 hours after I was informed the update was ready for sale, we are still receiving the same error.

I have found the following threads in the Apple Developer forums confirming this problem is not limited to our app: <sub><sup>(A login may be required)</sup></sub>

- [Promo-code redeemer getting "this code is for an app that is not c...](https://devforums.apple.com/message/472684#472684)
- [Promo codes broken on Verizon iPhones ?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/504643#504643)

I have submitted a bug report to Apple (ID 9905790) concerning the issue. At this time, I am unsure if this issue is related to Verizon devices or iOS 4.2.8. Once I receive a definitive answer I will post it. For now, a workaround that appears to be working for others which we have not yet tried, is to redeem and install through iTunes.

Since this appears to only affect Promo Code redemption and NOT store purchases, the issue has lost much of its urgency. However, if anyone is able to provide more information or a solution, it is still very much appreciated.

---

### Update:

I can confirm that redeeming the codes through iTunes and then installing to a Verizon device works fine. **This means the problem is *not* with the app or the build settings, but with the Verizon device App Store redemption.**

I have received one reply from Apple in response to my bug report asking me to verify if this occurs on 5.0b5. Unfortunately, as previously mentioned, we do not have developer access to the Verizon device (which is the entire reason for using a promotional code in this instance). I have asked them to confirm if this is a Verizon/iOS specific issue and will update this issue when I have more information.

Comment: +1 for a well-explained question and extra effort taken to avoid being spammy.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple documentation, it's just a matter of setting the deployment target:

> You have indicated that your binary requires iOS 4.3 or later. Apps that require iOS 4.3 or later will not be available to Verizon iPhone users. If your app could be compatible with earlier iOS versions, you may want to reject your binary and upload a new one that indicates the earliest compatible iOS.

That's the message that's normally appended to App Store emails when you have an app waiting for review.

So *in theory* it should 'just work'.

However, what would be interesting to know would be:

- Did you produce the promotional code before updating the app?
- If so, do you get the same results with a promo code generated after updating the app (you never know with the App Store / iTunes Connect...)
- After 24 hours are you still seeing the same issue? (24 hours being the normal App Store 'refresh period')

Sorry, I could not provide you with more concrete answers. At times it does feel like the App Store is held together with string, so it wouldn't be completely surprising if it was some value being kept around that should have been knocked back when you updated the app.

That said, it's a little strange that your app wouldn't work on the Verizon phone when you built it for 3.x. Why is the Verizon device not available for Xcode deployment? Is it because you don't have one to hand (understandable), or is it something else? There's no reason why it shouldn't be able to have ad-hocs thrown on it.

Comment: I agree it should *just work*, which is part of why I was so surprised by this behavior. I tried both a promo code previously generated (received an expired message) and then one that was generated just this morning specifically for the new version of the app.  However, the update has been out less than 24 hours (Currently 17 hours). It would be very interesting to see if this problem is corrected as Apple's servers are refreshed. I will certainly try again throughout the day.

Comment: We do not have a Verizon device for testing (Didn't think we'd need one since we already have multiple AT&T devices). The device being used belongs to a friend who is not open to Ad Hoc distribution (so this is unavailable because of the user not the device).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! To be honest, I'm not that hopeful it would change after 24 hours, but I have had issues in the past with things carrying over. It would make sense that Apple would store the deployment target somewhere outside the app itself in the store, so maybe that has not been updated yet. I would contact Apple directly if it doesn't seem to have resolved itself within 24 hours.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still isn't working (see update). I will attempt to contact Apple directly as advised, but I generally place more confidence in the SO community. Thanks for your help, I'll keep you updated on the progress!

Answer (score 1):

This is pure speculation:

Since there's a different build of iOS for the Verizon phone, maybe under the hood all apps on the appstore are available twice - one time signed for use on the AT&T version of iOS and one time signed for the Verizon version. The Appstore would deliver the appropriate version depending on your device.

If this would be the case and since redemption codes existed before the Verizon line of phones, it may be that redemption codes point to one version of the app only, leading the appstore to believe it is incompatible when redeemed on the "wrong" phone.

End of speculation.

I'd suggest instructing your friend to buy the app (if it's not too costly) and paying him the money back. If this works, then cleary what we're dealing with is a bug in Apples gift code system and you should be filing a bug report about this.

Btw: you're not alone with this problem. Although they didn't resolve it, the guys on [this forum](http://www.iphoneforums.net/forum/iphone-apps-20/truecaller-%5Bfeedback-thread%5D-16845/index2.html) mention the exact same situation.

Comment: They can't be using carrier-specific signing.  If you download an application from iTunes on the desktop, it has no idea what carrier your devices use (or even if they use a carrier).  Similarly, you can purchase an application on a Verizon device, sync it with iTunes, and install it on an AT&T (or other carrier) one.

Comment: Good point. So forget about my speculations... I'd file a bug with apple nevertheless, especially if the app can be purchased regularly on a Verizon phone. They've responded quite quickly to my last two bug reports, so I'd just give it a try.

Comment: @Toastor it was an interesting theory:) I'm beginning to believe the issue is not related to my app or my codes at all, but with how either the Verizon devices or iOS 4.2.8 handles promo code redemption (see my update above). +1 for providing a link showing we aren't alone, I appreciate it!